# can you please explain this ouptut means ,bad sectors are fixed

Tags: gparted

```
    GParted 0.30.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sda1  00:08:01    ( SUCCESS )
        
calibrate /dev/sda1  00:00:42    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sda1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 1953128447
size: 1953126400 (931.32 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:06:53    ( SUCCESS )
        
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 '/dev/sda1'  00:06:53    ( SUCCESS )
        
Error reading block 255 (Input/output error). Ignore error? yes

Force rewrite? yes

Resize inode not valid. Recreate? yes

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (23512, counted=23513).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong (240029359, counted=240029360).
Fix? yes


/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

11 inodes used (0.00%, out of 61038592)
0 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
0 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 2/1
4111440 blocks used (1.68%, out of 244140800)
0 bad blocks
0 large files

0 regular files
2 directories
0 character device files
0 block device files
0 fifos
0 links
0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
0 sockets
------------
2 files
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:26    ( SUCCESS )
        
resize2fs -p '/dev/sda1'  00:00:26    ( SUCCESS )
        
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
The filesystem is already 244140800 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!

========================================
```

Comment: Hello. This site explains what bad sectors are. https://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting